# How to Compare the files in local system folder

Tags: bash

How to compare the files from local system folder, whether they have same column name or not using bash script.
As per the business requirement will create some files from sql and will save it in to local system folder. After that we need to check all the files does it have a same columns(NAME/COUNTRY/STATE/PHNO) using bash script.

Comment: There are built-in utilities in GNU Linux to compare files such as `cmp`, `diff`, `diff3`, `sdiff`

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more explanation if you want a helpful answer. What folder(s) are you wanting to compare, what are their paths? What sort of comparison are you wanting to make, and which files should be compared? Give examples if possible, it makes things much easier to understand. As it stands, your question really isn't answerable.

Comment: @typecasto Updated please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to check the first line of each file, which contains those column headings. If you have a 'known good' file to compare with, we can use `head -n 1` to grab that first line from each file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Set these to suit your system
#
GOOD_FILE=/home/giri/sql_export_template.txt
SAVED_FILES=/local/system/folder/sql*.txt
#
GOOD_HEAD=$(head -n 1 $GOOD_FILE)
for TEST_FILE in $SAVED_FILES; do
  TEST_HEAD=$(head -n 1 $TEST_FILE)
  if [ "$TEST_HEAD" == "$GOOD_HEAD" ]; then
    echo "Good file: $TEST_FILE"
  else
    echo "Bad file:  $TEST_FILE"
  fi
done
```

Comment: I have tried the above script while test it i have provided the same file. but its just showing bad file path

Comment: If file format is in .dsv . in this scenario how can we achieve this